# How to display the point value in the line chart stroke of google api chart?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I am using linechart in google api chart. In this chart i need to display the vaxis value above point.but i am using annotation.It's create point value in near haxis .But i need above the point.

**Actual chart:**

[image]

**Expected chart:**

[image]

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() {

                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
                    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});

                    data.addRows([
                        ['2008', 23, 23],
                        ['2009', 145, 145],
                        ['2010', 245, 245],
                        ['2011', 350, 350]
                    ]);                

                    var options = {
                        width: 400,
                        height: 100,
                        pointSize: 4,
                        legend: {position: 'none'},
                        chartArea: {
                            left: 0,
                            top: 10,
                            width: 400,
                            height: 50},
                        vAxis: {
                            baselineColor: '#fff',
                            gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}
                        },
                        tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
                        annotation: {
                            1: {
                                style: 'none'
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);                
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to correct the order of the column defintion:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
```

Edit: See asgallant's comment on the correct order of columns. My text below isn't fully correct.

Although [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole) isn't that clear about it, you should always specify the x-axis first, then the values and put stuff like annotations at the end.

Comment: The annotations don't go at the end, they go after the column they apply to.  If you want annotations on the domain axis, the annotation column should be second.  If you want the annotations on the first data series, the annotation column needs to immediately follow it.  If you have two series of data, and want to annotate the first, the annotation column would have to go between the two series' columns in the DataTable.

Comment: I am using add column format year, sales and annotation. but the chart having four point. In this chart first two v axis value display in above point, remaining two v axis value display below the point. the chart shown updated answer.